# How to export output of redhsift unload command in csv format?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, amazon-redshift

I want to export the ouput of Unload command in Redshift to CSV format but it only gives option to produce a gzip file

Answer (score 1):

CSV (comma separated values) and Gzip (compression format) are separate things. Your output file can easily be both CSV and Gzip compressed.

If you want *uncompressed* CSV files then you can specify `DELIMITER AS ','` and *leave off* the `GZIP` option in your `UNLOAD` statement.

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM venue') 
TO 's3://mybucket/venue_tab_'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>'
DELIMITER AS ',' 
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its really helpful. Can you please tell me what to do If I want the file with .csv extension.  Because when I use the option "PARALLEL OFF" and save the file as XYZ.csv as in (TO 's3://mybucket/XYZ.csv '),  the actual output file comes as XYZ.csv000 and I have to convert its extension manually every time after downloading. Thanks in advance